# How much torque do I need to lift 1,000 pounds?

Tags: torque

So, I have a 1,000 pounds load.

What would be the required torque in inch/pounds to lift that load for a motor?

If the motor is installed at the center of the radius generating that torque, does it matter how long the radius is if the end requirement still 1,000 pounds load?

Would the answer be 1,000 in-lbs?

Comment: You are asking two questions.  "How much torque..." -- the answer is "does not compute", because the dimensions don't work out.  The other question *appears* to be "how big of a drum or pulley do I need", but it's not clear.  Please narrow it down.

Comment: I was watching a YouTube video about p** in stackoverflow...  Good thing I only come like twice a year around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any torque and power demand greater than your motor rating will cause it to stall.
for a 1000lbs.inch motor the pully's radius r must be, $$r < 1 \ \text{inch}$$

Otherwise you need a gear. Also the motor must have at least the power of,

$$P= 9.8  \cdot 1000\cdot 0.45 \ lbs/kg \cdot0.305 \ ft/meters=1345 \ \text{watts}$$
This is if you want to lift it in 1 second. If you want to lift it in 10 seconds then the power will be 134.5 watts, but the required torque  will still be the same.

Comment: So, if I have a 1,000 lbs-inch motor rating,  and I put it on the center of a 10 inch radius.. how many pounds could it lift?

Comment: 100lbs. The rest of this text is just to pad the comment.